# After logging in https://xp0cm.localhost/sitecore, I am getting an error saying "This site can't be reached"

Tags: sitecore-client, training-certification

I am following the sitecore developer fundamentals tutorial.  I was able to launch this site, https://xp0cm.localhost/ but when I tried to launch the site to login it took me several minutes of refreshing the page to be able to sign in.  Once I was able to sign in, the site refuses to connect.  My network connection is strong.  My containers are running.  I checked my firewall settings for google as well as Microsoft Edge and both allowed.  I disconnected from my VPN as well and still not able to launch the site.  Has anyone else had this issue or have any suggestions?

Comment: did you try by giving permission to your website folder.

Comment: @RishirajShekhawat I am not sure how to do that.  When I look at the security settings for google chrome and Microsoft edge they have public, private, and domain checked.  Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Can you check if you get any errors on the CM and ID containers? You should also verify if all of the containers are marked as healthy.

Comment: All containers are marked as healthy.